# cakephp not connecting to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, cakephp-2.1

I have successfully added mongodb to my server and I am able to work from the mongo shell no problem, I can also connect to the database from php just fine.  I have also downloaded and semi successfully installed the plugin for mongodb and cakephp.  However I am now stuck with cakephp not able to connect to the database.  I have followed both ichikawa's github and mark story's web page on the subject but neither has helped get over this hump.  Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should try to get this hooked up and running?

Comment: It's the mongoDB database running on the same host where cakePHP is located? Are you connecting with localhost?

Comment: Could you post the errors you are getting when you try to connect?

Comment: Answer to Carlos is yes and yes. the error for shelman is Error: Call to a member function getMessage() on a non-object File: D:\Apache24\htdocs\mongo_service\app\View\Pages\home.ctp Line: 114

Comment: That message is from your code trying to call getMessage on an invalid variable... which one is that at line 114?

Comment: line 114 reads echo $connectionError->getMessage(); which is the false section of if ($connected && $connected->isConnected()):

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and a buddy found a link that told us to replace line 185 of /app/Plugin/Mongodb/Model/Datasource/MongodbSource.php.  Here is the old line and the new line.

```
// $this->connection = new Mongo($host, array("persist" => $this->config['persistent']));
$this->connection = new Mongo($host);
```

I can try to locate the URL but the solution was above.

Answer (score 0):

Because your server using mongodb driver 1.x. Let's fix:

In app/Plugin/Monggodb/MongodbSource.php (line 197), find:

```
else if ($this->_driverVersion >= '1.3.0') {
                $this->connection = new $class($host);  // mongodb 2.x             
            }
```

replace:

```
else if ($this->_driverVersion >= '1.3.0' && $this->_driverVersion < '2.0') {
$this->connection = new $class("mongodb://loginID:password@IP"); // mongodb 1.5.6, loginID: your mongodb user login;     
}
```

With above code, you changed connect string, because connect string had different between mongo 2.x and 1.x

Vote if it's right! Fun!